# SQL Server 2008 - How to update a field with DELETE trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to update a field in the same table that the record is being deleted from but not too sure how.  The table is pretty simple and has a self reference on it:

```
UserID    FName   EmailAddress  EmailUserID
1         Frank   frank@g.com   2
2         Jane    jane@g.com    NULL
3         John    john@g.com    1
4         Brett   brett@g.com   2
```

Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CAT_DeleteUser]
   ON  Users
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Users
    SET EmailUserID = NULL
    WHERE EmailUserID = ID_OF_DELETED_USER <-- don't know how to get this

END
```

So if I delete Jane (UserID = 2), I'd like the trigger to update any record with the EmailUserID of 2.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You know that this will only work if you *don't* have a self-referencing foreign key, right? Which means you could stuff any value in EmailUserID and SQL Server is not going to complain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if you set up the table with a proper `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, an after trigger is not going to do the job. The `DELETE` happens logically before the operations in the trigger, so you will get:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint ...
```

So if you do want data integrity so that nobody can stuff garbage into the EMailUserID column, you can use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FName  NVARCHAR(32),
    EmailAddress VARCHAR(320),
    EmailUserID INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Users(UserID)
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CAT_DeleteUser] 
ON dbo.Users
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- clean up references first
    UPDATE u SET u.EmailUserID = NULL
        FROM dbo.Users AS u
        INNER JOIN deleted AS d
        ON u.EmailUserID = d.UserID;

    -- now delete the row
    DELETE u
    FROM dbo.Users AS u
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
    ON u.UserID = d.UserID;
END
GO
```

Sample try create a copy of `dbo.Users`, as above, in `tempdb`, then run this):

```
INSERT dbo.Users(UserID, FName, EmailAddress, EmailUserID) VALUES
(1,'Frank','frank@g.com',2   ),
(2,'Jane ','jane@g.com ',NULL),
(3,'John ','john@g.com ',1  ),
(4,'Brett','brett@g.com',2  );

SELECT * FROM dbo.Users;
GO

DELETE dbo.Users WHERE UserID = 2;
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Users;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Users;
GO
```

Answer (score 7):

You may use AFTER DELETE Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CAT_DeleteUser] ON  Users
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Users
    SET EmailUserID = NULL
    FROM Users
    JOIN DELETED
      ON Users.EmailUserID = Deleted.UserID

END
```

Comment: I've made two corrections. There is no ID column; corrected it to be UserID. Also qualified the join because EmailUserID exists in both Users and deleted - this should fail parsing due to ambiguous column name.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, got the question wrong the first time... An after trigger is possible in this case:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CAT_DeleteUser]
   ON  Users
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Users
    SET EmailUserID = NULL
    WHERE EmailUserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM DELETED)

END
```

Comment: Can you explai n this briefly?  By the looks of this, this would update the user table on where the UserID is the DELETE UserID, unless you meant to put WHERE EmailUserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM DELETED).

Comment: @Robert: You want to update the user table and set the column EmailUserID to null if the row was affected by the original delete statement, right? Assuming the UserID is the PK of the table, the trigger sets EmailUserID to null in all the rows, that were meant to be deleted by the original delete statement.

Comment: I've also made a correction here. You were updating the row where UserIDs matched. I agree with @Oleg you need to look more closely at the question.